# Trying to remember a classic board game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to remember the name of a game so I can look up strategies for it for my discrete math class.

The game is laid out with however many rows of marbles or stones and each player can choose however many stones they want from one row per turn, where the object of the game is to have their opponent choose the last stone.

It's a very old game and I'm interested in the math behind the game. I just can't remember its name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called Nim, and it's an excellent (and common) game for discrete math studies.
[Wikipedia's article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)